# Adding and Removing text from %var% - Batch - Simple

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering whether someone could simply explain to me how to Add and Remove specific keywords/text from a Variable in batch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use text replacement: `set var=%var:foo=%` to remove `foo` from `%var%`.

> Environment variable substitution has been enhanced as follows:
>
> ```
> %PATH:str1=str2%
> ```
>
> would expand the PATH environment variable, substituting each
>   occurrence of "str1" in the expanded result with "str2".  "str2" can
>   be the empty string to effectively delete all occurrences of "str1"
>   from the expanded output.  "str1" can begin with an asterisk, in which
>   case it will match everything from the beginning of the expanded
>   output to the first occurrence of the remaining portion of str1.

To add things to an environment variable you can either add it at the beginning or end:

```
set "var=beginning %var%"
set "var=%var% end"
```

or muck around with substrings if you need something in the middle:

```
set "var=%var:~0,5% middle %var:~5%"
```

Comment: @Moonicorn: Added another paragraph on that.

Comment: It is important to note that the variable substitution feature is case insensitive. CMD.EXE does not have a convenient way to do case sensitive string substitution.